# How to render Next JS page on a custom Express server

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, multer

I am working on a NextJS project, and I need a form loaded on server, to be able to upload files so for that I used multer along with express in a custom server.

Now on GET request I want to render a specific page, but I am not sure how I can do this. I don't want to have any html in the server, just a call to the page. Is this even possible?

```js
server.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.send(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<myPage />))
});
```

when I start the server I am getting the following:

> /Users/MONOLITH-Strat-Audrey/Projects/sandbox/multer-file-upload/server.js:41
>
> `res.send(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<myPage />))`
>
> ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

In the server I am calling the page like this, which obviously doesn't work.

```
const myPage = require('./pages/index')
```

For references, this is my github with all the code.
[Github Repo](https://github.com/monicasalamanca/MulterFileUpload)

Comment: did you import react ?

Comment: @Nirus just did, I missed adding react, but still doesn't work

Comment: If answer helped please accept it. It might help others too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is a multipart error in your code.**

- Never import React components in **server.js** or node entry point file.
- All pages should reside inside **pages** directory for **Next.js** to
  parse it and serve.

---

#### Below are the changes made and it started working

Remove or comment below line from **server.js**

```
const myPage = require('./pages/index')
```

In **line 48 - server.js**

```
  server.get('/',function(req,res){
    // res.write(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<myPage />))
    return app.render(req, res, '/', query)
  });
```

In your **components/file.js** `render` method return the jsx

```
class File extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<form action="/uploadfile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"> 
      <input type="file" name="myFile" />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload a file"/>
    </form>)
  }
}
```

---

### References for custom server using Next.js

- SSR in ***Next.js*** -
  https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#two-forms-of-pre-rendering
- ***Next.js*** Custom server -
  https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server
- Custom server example -
  https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server

Comment: I understand that you should try to never do this to avoid perfomance issues. But sometimes there are cases where you need to do this. I was trying to follow this tutorial. https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-server-rendering/

Comment: @Monica if you use **next.js** you dont have to do heavy lifting yourself by using hydration & domToString methods manually. Tutorial you pointed out is purely react SSR, no Next.js. **Anyways i have created a pull request on the GitHub for your repo correcting the code. please accept it.** Happy learning!